# How to remove windscribe public key in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, gnupg, keyrings

I can't seem to locate the public key of windscribe and remove it.

My issue:

```
$ sudo apt update
Err:16 https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                      
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D5AD3767530B91D0
Reading package lists... Done       
W: GPG error: https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D5AD3767530B91D0
E: The repository 'https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I tried `sudo apt-key list` and `sudo apt-key finger` but could not find `windscribe` or `D5AD3767530B91D0` or any public key with `91D0`.

I tried `sudo apt-key del "D5AD 3767 530B 91D0"` and `sudo apt-key del 530B91D0` but the issue still persists.

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: @guiverc Linux 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu. It is not Zesty though.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: FYI:  It belongs in your question, esp. given the off-topic detail present.

Comment: @guiverc Why do you regard my question as off-topic given that Ubuntu 18.04 isn't EOL?

Comment: There was nothing that said 18.04, the only release mentioned was *zesty* or 17.04 https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/01/17/ubuntu-17-04-zesty-zapus-reached-end-of-life-on-january-13-2018/  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @guiverc But this issue is occurring in Linux 5.4.0-66-generic #74~18.04.2-Ubuntu. It is not Zesty though. Can't understand how  this issue can even happen.

Comment: That's a kernel and not a release of Ubuntu; that kernel is used by multiple systems (including some off-topic; it's the 20.04 GA kernel (on-topic), it's the 18.04 HWE kernel, etc   the 18.04 detail narrows it done some, but still isn't specific enough to guarantee on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` that contains the reference to the https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu or it can be in file in the `/etc/apt/sources.d/` directory. Either way it needs to be removed for it to stop asking for the key.